# how to point to a html template in production using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, path

So im using data-ng-include to display a html template in a div. The problem that i am running into is that in my local... the path to the html works and everything works fine. However once i run gulp build and run the app in production, i think the path is incorrect and the UI cant find the correct template to display.

for example..

HTML:

```
<div id="abc" ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-controller="splitController" data-ng-include="templateURL"></div>
</div>
```

TemplateUrl:

```
$scope.templateURL = '/app/components/preview/split/split.html';
```

Anyone know how to locate the html path for when the app gets built into prod?

Thanks

Comment: when you run the app, what is the path it is trying to pull?

Comment: its pulling https://productionUrl.com/app/components/preview/split/split.html but getting a 404 not found

Comment: but when going from localhost it works fine in https://localhost:8080/app/components/preview/split/split.html

Comment: hmm, have you tried using a path relative to the html you posted above? Rather than an absolute path. You could also try putting the path directly into the ng-include (just to rule things out) like `ng-include="'path/to/your/file.html'"`, note the single quotes in the double as the answer below was getting at

Comment: also, go directly to your split.html file on your production server just to verify it is actually there.

Comment: yea thats the thing i think the html file isnt there

Comment: because when you do a build....it like parses all the files into like 1 file and if i actually go to  productionUrl.com/app/components/preview/split/split.html..its not there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161835/discussion-between-ronnie-and-zomdar).

Answer (score 0):

first, separate your controller and ng-include. create separate elements for each

```
<div id="abc" >
    <div ng-controller="splitController" ng-init="init()">
         <div ng-include="templateURL"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the url, make sure to add single quotes inside the double quotes.

```
$scope.templateURL = "'/app/components/preview/split/split.html'";
```

Comment: adding the single quotes inside the double quotes actually threw and error bc if adds the single quotes to the path

Comment: in order to identify the path, `ng-include` need to wrap around with single quotes

Comment: If his path is defined in the controller, you don't need to wrap it in single and double quotes. That is only if the path was injected straight into the `ng-include`. Since he is using the variable, `templateURL`, the way he has it is fine.